# How can I reshape the output of a keras model?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, reshape, shapes

I would like to build a Recurrent Network using the functional API in Keras but change the output shape. For now, the output shape is (n,1), where n is the number of input vectors, and if I understood correctly the additional dimension represents the number of batches. I would like model.predict to have an output that is of shape (n,) (so that it has the same shape as y_test). I know how to reshape the output after running model.predict, but is there a way to change the network so that running model.predict already has the desired shape?

I also tried to use a Reshape layer but this did not change the output shape.

Would really appreciate any idea & help! Here is a toy example:

```
#random toy example
X=np.random.rand(100,3)
y=np.random.rand(100)
 
X_train, X_test = np.vsplit(X,[80])
y_train, y_test = np.split(y,[80])

#define model
inputs=Input(shape=(3,1))
h=Conv1D(filters=64,kernel_size=2, activation='relu')(inputs)
h=MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(h)
h=Flatten()(h)
h=Dense(50, activation='relu')(h)
outputs=Dense(1)(h)

model=Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
 
#fit model
model.fit(X_train, y_train,verbose=0)
print(model.predict(X_test).shape)
```

which prints the shape
`(20, 1)`

Using a Reshape Layer does not change the output shape. Am I using it wrong?

```
inputs=Input(shape=(3,1))
h=Conv1D(filters=64,kernel_size=2, activation='relu')(inputs)
h=MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(h)
h=Flatten()(h)
h=Dense(50, activation='relu')(h)
h=Dense(1)(h)
outputs=Reshape(target_shape=(1,))(h)

model=Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
 
#fit model
model.fit(X_train, y_train,verbose=0)
print(model.predict(X_test).shape)
```

Comment: As I know, you cannot reshape your output as (n,) because loss function calculate the loss by using the information of that dimension d (n,d), which is 1 in your case. So change the shape of y_test from (n,) to (n,1)

Answer (score 0):

As you understood, most of the `tf.keras.layers` layers work with the undefined batch dimension of size `None`. If you need to reshape your output this way, you need to use the `Lambda` layer.

```
outputs_1d = Lambda(lambda x: tf.squeeze(x))(outputs)
```

and,

```
model=Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs_1d)
```